# Firestore updateData FieldValue for an auto-generated ID

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to auto-increment a LIKES counter when a button is pressed.

I am using Firestore and my document ID's are auto-generated for 100's of records in my database.

When attempting to call a document dynamic ID, I'm receiving the following Xcode error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type 'String'

I have also tried the following approach to call the dynamic document ID: document("(user)") (this causes the app to crash due to "//" in a path)

```
@IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let likeCounter = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(user)
    likeCounter.updateData([
        "likes": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
        ])
    }
```

Comment: The error is unfortunately all we can say: you're passing an argument of type `User` to `document(...)`, while `document(...)` expects to get a string. How does `user` relate to the document that you're trying to update?

Comment: You need to pass the string ID of the document to update, not some other object.  If you don't know the ID, you won't be able to read or write the document.

Comment: Frank, Doug, thx for the comments. To workaround and find a solution, I added a new field to the collection for each auto-generated-document-ID. When a document ID is automatically created... ie: 0K3EwERkY60vuz0qsPEF, I now capture it via docRef.id and write it to the collection as 'userID: 0K3EwERkY60vuz0qsPEF' so I can use it as a sting. Now my counter works with .collection("posts").document("userID"). it might not be the most efficient solution, but it works.